# How can I open Instagram links inside my Twitter app?

Tags: twitter, instagram

I'm looking for a way to open Instagram photos inside my Twitter app. I'm using Plume now, and it can open almost all the photos inside the app. When press and hold on the link the photo expands to the actual size, so Plume doesn't open the browser for every photo, and it's very convenient and quick. However, this technique doesn't work with Instagram links. When you select those, Plume opens the browser and redirects to the Instagram site, which takes several seconds. Twitter for Android is worse - it opens every photo link in the browser.

Is there a way for me to open photo links inside either of these apps quickly? If not, are there any alternative Twitter clients that support this?

Comment: Twitter for Android should show the image if you click on the tweet itself and view it, rather than clicking the link.  I don't know if it handles Instagram links though.

Comment: Well, it doesn't